# ReSharper Background Colour Display Item Name

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I have just upgraded to ReSharper 6.0 and one thing I have noticed is that there seems to be a new background colour display item. It may be used in other places but I have noticed it in string.Format() operations. For example when I do something like this:

[image]

and then move the cursor to {0} I get this:

[image]

Obviously that is a bit hard to read but I can't change it as I can't figure out which item refers to it within the Tools->Options->Fonts and Colors menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **ReSharper Format String Item** (for format string items) and **ReSharper Matched Format String Item** (for parameters)

Comment: Perfect, ReSharper Matched Format String was the one I needed. Thanks for the quick response!